# "Rolled off with"

Tags: phrase-usage

Here's a sentence I've written:

> Greg gave Phil the finger then rolled off with Simon.

And here's a question:

If Simon is in a wheelchair and Greg, who's pushing the wheelchair, walks away from Phil with Simon - is it perfectly okay to write "rolled off with Simon"?

Comment: Putting aside the matter of whether it's "okay" to write about "giving someone the finger" in the first place, you seem to be just asking whether it's idiomatically natural to metaphorically extend the rolling action associated with Simon's wheelchair to Greg when he ***walks*** away (pushing Simon or not, who cares?). So far as I'm concerned it makes no sense to do this - it seems like something of a "mixed metaphor" usage to me (or at least, "confused").

Comment: ...note that you'll rarely if ever see things like *She wheeled off with the baby [in a pram]* (you might see *She wheeled the baby off,* but that's a different construction).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds fine to me. it's idiomatic and obvious what is going on, and emphasises the fact that Simon is on wheels. It also seems to express a fine degree of nonchalance.

If you really want to emphasise the wheely nature of the action, you could use "trundle",  which is even more amusingly wheely, and has connotations of railway trucks and unwieldy machinery travelling slowly and laboriously.